# Javascript hover effect doesn't work on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad

I want to create a homepage with three images swapping when hover on the menu bar. 
The following mouseover scripts works on PC but not on iPad. 
How could I fix this problem?

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href onmouseover="myFunction()">
    <h2>Investments by strategy</h2>
</a>


<a style="text-decoration:none" href onmouseover="myFunction2()">
      <h2>Investments by geography</h2>
</a>      

      <a style="text-decoration:none" href onmouseover="myFunction3()">   
    <h2>Investments by type</h2>
</a>      





<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "images/img002.png";
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "images/pie2.png";
}


function myFunction3() {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "images/test.png";
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

iPad (or any other touch screen device) does NOT support mouse over effects. In short, you can't "fix" this problem.

*(well, your device can't detect where your finger is hovering over the screen, right?)*

Comment: Right. I mean can I change the script to something like touchstart: function(){}?

Comment: Re-think your user experience on mobile platform. Mobile websites won't have such effects.